# How to make a centered hexagon door consisting of 6 triangles?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to create a hexagonal airlock. It would consist of 6 triangular parts. I would like to use some tool that would allow me to edit all those parts at once. I'd also want it to animate them accordingly to this sketch:
[image]

From what I've read the best solution appeared to be using an array modifier on the triangular element with an object offset using an empty element at 0,0,0 and rotated 60' on Z axis. Instead of the hexagon, I've created something like this.

[image]
I played a little with the coordinates of the empty point and received somewhat what I wanted, but it is definitely imperfect.

[image]
How can I create the hexagon, so that all the vertices are aligned and it would be easy to animate the mentioned way?

Comment: your demand has changed... first you wanted to create 6 concentric triangles that you could modify at once, now you want to animate them, which is a completely different subject, so please try to give as many informations as possible on what your purpose is

Comment: I've added a solution for the animation, tell me if it's ok

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the **modeling**, here are 3 ways:

First the **simplest way**, if you don't need your triangles to be linked:

- Create a circle (6 vertices, *Fill Type* > *Triangle Fan*).
- Choose *Edge Select* mode, select all the concentric edges and press <kbd>V</kbd> to rip, then <kbd>enter</kbd> to validate right away. Now each triangle is independent.

If you want your triangles to be linked (so that you can continue to work its topology) you could use **linked duplications**:

- Create a 3 vertices circle.
- Put its origin on one of its vertices (or put the 3D cursor on one of its vertices and choose the 3D cursor as *Pivot Center*).
- Duplicate your triangle with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to confirm right away.
- Make your linked copy rotate 60° on the Z axis.
- Make a second linked copy and make it rotate 120°, etc...

You could also use an ***Array* modifier**:

- Create a 3 vertices circle.
- Put its origin on one of its vertices.
- Put an empty on the same point.
- Give your triangle an *Array* modifier, and choose the empty as *Object*.
- Rotate the empty 60° on the Z axis.

[image]

For the **animation**, you can do it this way:

- Separate each triangle.
- Set the origin on the geometry of each triangle with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.
- Choose *Pivot Point* option > *Median Point* and enable the *Manipulate Center Point* option (don't forget to disable it when you'll have finished to keyframe).
- In the *Timeline*, put your cursor at frame 0.
- Select all your triangles and create a keyframe with <kbd>i</kbd> > *LocRotScale*.
- In the *Timeline*, put your cursor at frame X.
- With all your triangles selected, scale up with <kbd>S</kbd>. With the *Manipulate Center Point* option enabled the triangles will go away from each others instead of scaling.
- Create a new keyframe with <kbd>i</kbd> > *LocRotScale*.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I could modify all the triangle parts at once? I would prefer not to modify them individually.

Comment: I've edited, in that case you can use an Array

Answer (score 3):

For the animation part, maybe a simple way is to **use shape keys**

[image]

From the array modifier setting you already have, add a base and another shape key named 'opening' in the object data property panel. That allow to do it without breaking the modifier setting.

The shape key is simply defined like below and the animation is done keyframing the shape key value:

[image]

**Or another possibility is to hook the vertices**

[image]

In edit mode select all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hook to an empty. Then animate the empty.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

first add a cilinder and go to the settings in the left panel and set it up to 6 vertices and you are done :D happy blending!!  [image]
[image]

Comment: Like I've said, I will want to modify individual triangular parts with translations and shaping into more complex form, so simple hexagon cylinder won't do.

Comment: @Momonga-sama you mean you want to make a object that could tranform in several shapes like from a star to a hexagon?

Comment: For example, I would want them to move and form a hollow hexagon between the triangles. I would also want to modify every triangle to make their shape more complex. Editing them one by one will be time-consuming, that's why I decided to use the array function.