# cut and rotate out parts of sphere evenly

Tags: animation

I'm trying to replicate the following animation but as my knowledge is very limited I cannot figure out how to do it.

So, basically what I want to do is to cut a sphere into 8 different pieces, then rotate and spread out the parts evenly like in the image. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Sphere explostion]

Comment: you can use the knife or knife project tool to cut it from the top view, parent all the parts to an empty, make the separation animation, then rotate the empty

Comment: OK, I manage to cut and parent the parts to an empty. But I cannot yet figure out how to make the separate animation/ separate the parts evenly.Can you please give me a hint.

Comment: you animate them before the empty animation, enable the Manipulate Center Point option (Pivot Point > Only Origins in 2.8)

Comment: see this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130554/how-to-make-a-centered-hexagon-door-consisting-of-6-triangles

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the instructions.

Comment: make sure the origin is on the geometry of each part, otherwise it won't separate correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips. Really appreciate your help.
 Here's my result
https://media.giphy.com/media/dy9fOaevJUmi2KN8yG/giphy.gif

Comment: nice! you're welcome!